Fractal Geometry: Show that the Hausdorff dimension of a set and its image under $f(x)=x^2$ are the same.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x) = x^2$, and let $F$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\text{dim}_Hf(F) = \text{dim}_\mathrm{H} F$. Here $\text{dim}_\mathrm{H}$ refers to Hausdorff dimension.

It was easy to show that $\text{dim}_\mathrm{H} f(F) \leq \text{dim}_\mathrm{H} F$ since $f$ is Lipschitz in bounded regions. For the reverse inequality I am stuck. I can do it in the case that $F \subset \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ because then $f$ is invertible and $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz in regions bounded away from $0$. In general, I don't know how to deal with the fact that $f$ is not injective.

Proof. Let $F_k=F \cap[\frac{1}{k}, k]$. If $x, y \in F_k$, then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|x^2-y^2\right|=|(x-y)(x+y)|=|x-y||x+y|
$$
by the homogeneity of $|\cdot|$.
We get
$$
\frac{2}{k}|x-y| \leq|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 2 k|x-y| .
$$
Thus $f$ is a bi-Lipschitz map on $F_k$.
The following proposition explains what a bi-Lipschitz map is and gives a result that we will use.

Proposition A. If $f: F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a bi-Lipschitz transformation, that is,
$$
c_1|x-y| \leq|f(x)-f(y)| \leq c|x-y| \quad(x, y \in F),
$$
where $0<c_1 \leq c<\infty$, then $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathrm{H}} f(F)=\operatorname{dim}_{\mathrm{H}} F$.

By this Proposition, $\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} f\left(F_k\right)=$ $\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} F_k$.
Similarly, if $G_k=F \cap[-k,-\frac{1}{k}]$, then $\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} f\left(G_k\right)=\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} G_k$.
Now $$F=(\color{blue}{F \cap\{0\}}) \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(F_k \cup G_k\right)$$ and $$f(F)=\color{green}{f(F \cap\{0\})} \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(f\left(F_k\right) \cup f\left(G_k\right)\right).$$ Since $\color{blue}{F \cap\{0\}}$ and $\color{green}{f(F \cap\{0\})}$ contain at most one point, they both have zero dimension. Thus, by countable stability,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} F & =\sup_{k\geq 1} \left\{\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} F_k, \operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} G_k\right\} \\
& =\sup_{k\geq 1} \left\{\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} f\left(F_k\right), \operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} f\left(G_k\right)\right\}=\operatorname{dim}_\mathrm{H} f(F),
\end{aligned}
$$
which ends our proof. $\quad\rule{2mm}{2mm}$

Countable stability. If $F_1, F_2, \ldots$ is a (countable) sequence of sets, then $$\operatorname{dim}_{\mathrm{H}} \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i=\sup _{1 \leq i<\infty}\left\{\operatorname{dim}_{\mathrm{H}} F_i\right\}.$$

